# Numpy array dimensions after zip()

Tags: python, numpy

I have two numpy 2D arrays x & y, with dimensions x(700,5) & y(10,5).

When I run the following command,

```
xy = list(zip(x.T, y.T))
```

I get a list with 5 tuples. In each tuple, there are two arrays with dimensions (700,) and (10,).

I need them to be (700,1) and (10,1) instead.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [128]: a = np.ones((5,3),int)
In [129]: a.T
Out[129]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])

In [131]: list(zip(a.T, (a+3).T))
Out[131]: 
[(array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1]), array([4, 4, 4, 4, 4])),
 (array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1]), array([4, 4, 4, 4, 4])),
 (array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1]), array([4, 4, 4, 4, 4]))]
```

`zip` iterates over the first dim of the inputs.  In this case it's the rows of transposed arrays.  So at each iteration is taking one row, a 1d array.  The result is a list of tuples, each tuple consisting of two 1d arrays.

---

We could add a dimension to `a` before processing:

```
In [132]: a=a[None,:,:]
In [133]: a.shape
Out[133]: (1, 5, 3)
In [134]: a.T.shape
Out[134]: (3, 5, 1)
In [135]: list(zip(a.T, (a+3).T))
Out[135]: 
[(array([[1],
         [1],
         [1],
         [1],
         [1]]), array([[4],
         [4],
         [4],
   ...
         [4],
         [4]]))]
In [136]: _[0][0].shape
Out[136]: (5, 1)
```

I  wouldn't describe that as pretty, but it seems to meet your requirements.

Or you could use a list comprehension to expand the zip, and add the dimension then:

```
In [139]: [(i[:,None],j[:,None]) for i,j in zip(a.T, (a[:2]+3).T)]
Out[139]: 
[(array([[1],
         [1],
         [1],
         [1],
         [1]]), array([[4],
         [4]])), (array([[1],
         [1],
         [1],
         [1],
         [1]]), array([[4],
         [4]])), (array([[1],
         [1],
         [1],
         [1],
         [1]]), array([[4],
         [4]]))]
```

This also works:

```
list(zip(*np.atleast_3d(a.T,b.T)))
```

`atleast_3d` can operate on a list of arrays, making each (M, N, 1).  It's a specialized function that I don't use very often.

Comment: It's just a coincidence but `np.atleast_3d` happens to do the trick: `list(zip(*map(np.atleast_3d, (x.T, y.T))))`.

Comment: @PaulPanzer, don't even need the map.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's exactly what I needed.